# Django custom QuerySet evaluation

Tags: python, django, customization, django-queryset

So `QuerySet`s are "lazy" and only run in certain instances (repr,list,etc.). I have created a custom `QuerySet` for doing many queries, but these could end up having millions of items!! **That is way more than I want to return**.

When returning the evaluated `QuerySet`, it should not have more than 25 results! Now I know I could do the following:

```
first = example.objects.filter(...)
last = first.filter(...)
result = last[:25]
#do stuff with result
```

but I will be doing so many queries with `example` objects that I feel it unnecessary to have the line `result = last[:25]`. **Is there a way to specify how a `QuerySet` is returned?**

If there is, how can I change it so that **whenever the `QuerySet` would be evaluated** it only returns the first `x` items in the `QuerySet` where, in this case, `x = 25`

## Important note:

slicing must be on evaluation because that way I can chain queries without limited results, but when I return a result upon evaluation, it would have a max of `x`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what your issue with slicing the queryset is. If it's the extra line of code or the hardcoded number that's bothering you, you can run

```
example.objects.filter(**filters)[:x]
```

and pass x into whatever method you're using.

Comment: it's the extra line of code, I know I can use `x`, I just feel it unnecessary because this will be called many times, like thousands, and I can't do it for each custom filter because slicing evaluates it and then you wouldn't be able to chain

Comment: Docs say: "Generally, slicing a QuerySet returns a new QuerySet – it doesn’t evaluate the query." So I'd say your answer is the way to go.

Comment: @möter "Generally", there are cases in which it does, time is excruciatingly important and I cannot risk it evaluating. Also this is for an API and it would break the API

Comment: @möter Plus, I would then have to put a slice at the end of every single query method, in which there are over 50 and many will continue to be added. If I could have it simply always return the first `x` results, that would be ideal.

Comment: @RyanSaxe Generally here means when not slicing with the 'step' argument.

Comment: @möter okay, then comes back to the original question, which is still not answered. I would have to add it to the end of every method, and methods are continually added. If this was in the evaluation of the queryset then it would be easier, less redundant, and stop a possibility of forgetting to add it at the end of the method and overloading the results.

Comment: I suppose you could wrap all of your queryset calls in a method that slices them before returning them. That way you can modify this behavior in one place in the future.

Comment: @red this is for an API, so that would be a very ugly requirement

Comment: If all other QuerySets are descended from the first, sliced QuerySet, you could just make a reference to that first one, then operate on it for the other queries.

Comment: @möter wait, slicing at all the methods wouldn't work either, you would not be able to get all the results because the first query would be limited to 25, that is also why slicing on evaluation is important

Comment: Maybe try the QuerySet.query.set_limits method.

Comment: @möter that could be it, I can't seem to find the documentation on that method, could you link me?

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/sql/query.py

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41734/discussion-between-ryan-saxe-and-moter)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom [Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/):

```
class LimitedNumberOfResultsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(LimitedNumberOfResultsManager, self).get_queryset()[:25]
```

*Note: You may think that adding a slice here will immediately evaluate the queryset. It won't. Instead information about the query limit will be saved to an underlying `Query` object and used later, during the final evaluation - as long as it is not overwritten by an  another slice in the meantime.*

Then add the manager to your model:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    # ...

    objects = LimitedNumberOfResultsManager()
```

After setting this up `YourModel.objects.all()` and other operations on your queryset will always return only up to 25 results. You can still overwrite this any time using slicing. For example:

This will return up to 25 resuls:

```
YourModel.objects.filter(lorem='ipsum')
```

but this will return up to 100 resuls:

```
YourModel.objects.filter(lorem='ipsum')[:100]
```

---

One more point. Overwriting the default manager may be confusing to other people reading your code. So I think it would be better to leave the default manager alone and use the custom one as an optional alternative:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    # ...

    objects = models.Manager()
    limited = LimitedNumberOfResultsManager()
```

With this set up this will return all results:

```
YourModel.objects.all()
```

and this will return only up to 25 results:

```
YourModel.limited.all()
```

---

Depending on your exact use case you man also want to look at [pagination in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/).